# Modeling Non-Stationary Series Using ARIMA

Tags: time-series, arima, unit-root

I am trying to model interest rate data using ARIMA in order to estimate the effect of an external shock. However, when I run the ADF and KPSS tests, both conclude that stationarity is rejected. My understanding is that this means that there is a unit root in the series, and that any external shock will be persistent forever. However, many posts suggest that differencing a non-stationary series will allow forecasting through ARIMA. Can a persistent shock be predicted through an ARIMA model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a random walk $y_t=y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$, i.e., an ARIMA(0,1,0).
Differencing gives $\Delta y_t=\epsilon_t$. When $E(\epsilon_t)=0$, that means our forecast given our information set at time $T$ for the change will be 
$$
E_T(\Delta y_{T+h})=0
$$
for any horizon $h=1,2,\ldots$.

You may now (always, not only for a random walk) write
$$
y_{T+h}=y_T+\Delta y_{T+1}+\ldots+\Delta y_{T+h}
$$
so that we can forecast the ARIMA process $y_t$ at $T+h$ as
$$
E_T(y_{T+h})=y_T+0
$$
Some terminology: ADF cannot reject stationarity, as the null is nonstationarity, so at best you may not reject the null of nonstationarity.

Comment: Now suppose that the ADF does not reject the null of nonstationarity, do we automatically assume that there is a unit root? What is the purpose to modeling a nonstationary series with ARIMA if all we are getting in the future is the previous value + a random error term?

Comment: Also, if the ADF test fails to reject the null hypothesis, and we are still able to fit an AR(1) model with a significant coefficient of 0.99, can we be confident in this coefficient or no?

Comment: Q1: Like with any other hypothesis test, not rejecting is not proof that the null is true, but common practice is to proceed as if it is, because the data does not provide evidence against the null.

Comment: Q2: first, a random walk is of course the simplest possible ARIMA process with $d>0$. But in essence, yes, that is the forecast, and it is the optimal forecast if the underlying process is a random walk, despite the fact that it is not an "exciting" one. Still, it may well be a plausible one. Think of stock prices, where the efficient market hypothesis strongly suggests that the best we can say about future stock prices (at least in the short run, abstracting from drift) is that they are just as likely to go up as down, so to stay where they are on average.

Comment: Q3: yes, the coefficient estimate in a regression of $y$ on its lag is consistent for the true value no matter if the true process is a stationary AR(1) or a random walk.

Comment: Ultimately, I want to apply a shock to a time series at time t, and see when the shock will disappear and go back to its original level as if the shock had not happened. The ADF test tells me that I can't reject the hypothesis of a unit root and therefore, any shock will be persistent forever. The AR(1) model tells me that the coefficient is 0.98, and therefore it will eventually (albeit in a long time) return to its original level. Is there a proper way to model the series and estimate the effect of a shock, or am I looking at this problem completely the wrong way?

Comment: No, you look at it the right way. There is indeed a discontinuity in the behavior of the process as $\rho\to1$, and still, it is difficult to distinguish in any finite sample if the AR-coefficient is unity or less than 1. Many contributions in the literature (local-to-unity processes, fractional integration etc.) can be seen as attempts to bridge that gap.

Comment: So if I want to simulate this shock, can I only use an AR process assuming the coefficient is less than 1? Because if I difference the series, I am essentially assuming that there is a unit root in the AR coefficient, right?

Comment: I do not see how you infer this from our discussion. My answer outlines precisely that you can perfectly well simulate shocks from a random walk, i.e., an AR process with coefficient equal to one.

Comment: Apologies, my response wasn't clear. I meant that to simulate a decaying shock over time, the coefficient has to be less than 1 - otherwise, the shock is permanent. Since the discontinuity at ρ→1 is significant, is there a common way to choose between the estimated ρ=0.98 from AR(1) and the assumed ρ=1 from the ADF test?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, you cannot get decaying shocks with a random walk. One common way are unit root tests, but as you noticed (and as any test), these are not perfect and may not allow you to distinguish with statistical precision $\rho=1$ from, say, $\rho=0.98$ in a finite sample.